# How to print a UITextField text by AirPrint

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, airprint

i am having this code to do the AirPrint the textview text

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnprintermainnote:(id)sender
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    print.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName =@"Nots of MyBibleApp";
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    print.printInfo = printInfo;
    print.showsPageRange = YES;
    print.printingItem = _txtmainnote.text;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *,BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *print,BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"houston we have a problem");
        }
    };
    [print presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

but i didn't get any popup for printer option like the default pinter option in iPad.am not using a bar button,i have a UIbutton.how to do this correctly,is there any mistake in my code?._txtmainnote is my textview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPrintInteractionController/printingItem), the `printingItem`:

> The object must be an instance of the `NSURL`, `NSData`, `UIImage`, or
>   `ALAsset` class.

so probably you have to pass something like:

```
NSData* data=[_txtmainnote.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
print.printingItem = data;
```

Comment: so the above my code is wrong?so i have to insert your code line too right?i had got the printpopup correctly,but i dint test it.

Comment: Try with a real AirPrint printer or with Printer Simulator Tool with your code first, if not works, try with my solution.

Comment: You know @Mat that realy doesn't work -- it's looking for a PDF file.  It's looks like there's no immediate way to render formatted text to Airprint .. which sucks.  (Of course you can print it, as a bitmap... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479985 )

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution,,just change this line of code  `[print presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];` to     `[print presentFromRect:CGRectMake(600, 650, 100, 200) inView:mainnotepageview animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];`
because am using iPad app.

Comment: This seems bizarre. It should work just fine (perhaps with a warning) with the simpler line of code there; I don't think the problem was related to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainnotepageview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text02;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

 - (IBAction)btnSettingsTapped:(id)sender
{
 NSMutableString *printBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@,  %@",self.myTextView.text, self.label.text];
//[printBody appendFormat:@"\n\n\n\nPrinted From *myapp*"];

UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.delegate = self;

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
printInfo.jobName = self.label.text;
pic.printInfo = printInfo;

UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:printBody];
textFormatter.startPage = 0;
textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;

pic.showsPageRange = YES;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};

//[pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.rightButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
[pic presentFromRect:CGRectMake(600, 650, 100, 200) inView:_mainnotepageview animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer